# Left and right eigenvalues are equivalent?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the following mathworld.wolframapha [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html)
, a proof that the left and right eigenvalues are exactly the same is given. I don't understand the reasoning in the paragraph after (12). Could someone please elaborate on that?

Comment: If you take the transpose of a ‘left eigenvalue’ equation you see that the left eigenvalues are right eigenvalues if the transpose of $A$. The result follows noting that the transpose has the same characteristic polynomial (hence the same eigenvalues) as $A$

Comment: Yeah but what does the person mean by “which are both 0 for arbitrary A and x?” Is it $\forall A,x (det(A-\lambda_1 I)=det(A-\lambda_2 I))\Rightarrow \lambda_1=\lambda_2$?

Comment: It’s not written very well. Forget that the equations are valid for any matrix $A$ (although it’s true). Just keep “for all $x$”. Then you see that the equation that defines the right eigenvalues (setting to zero the characteristic polynomial) is the same as that defining the left eigenvalues. I also wouldn’t use the expression “they are equivalent” although it’s kind of clear what he meant.